# What's the easiest way to summarize by group and for the whole sample?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, grouping, summarize

Suppose I have data that looks like this:

```
   Date       time     price minute FOMC  Daily.Return
   <date>     <time>   <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>
 1 2005-01-03 16:00:00  120.    960 FALSE       -1.24 
 2 2005-01-04 16:00:00  119.    960 FALSE       -1.44 
 3 2005-01-05 16:00:00  118.    960 FALSE       -0.354
 4 2005-01-06 16:00:01  119.    960 FALSE        0.245
 5 2005-01-07 15:59:00  119.    959 FALSE       -0.328
 6 2005-01-10 16:00:00  119.    960 FALSE        0.506
 7 2005-01-11 16:00:00  118.    960 FALSE       -0.279
 8 2005-01-12 16:00:01  119.    960 FALSE        0.329
 9 2005-01-13 16:00:00  118.    960 FALSE       -0.787
10 2005-01-14 16:00:00  118.    960 FALSE        0.372
```

I want to summarize `Daily.Return` per group using the `FOMC` variable which is either TRUE or FALSE. That is easy with dplyr. I get the following:

```
daily.SPY %>%  group_by(FOMC) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = 100 * mean(Daily.Return),
            Median = 100 * median(Daily.Return),
            Vol = 100 * sqrt(252) * sd(Daily.Return/100))
```

As expected, I get the following tibble back:

```
FOMC      Mean Median   Vol
  <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 FALSE  0.00551   5.24  14.9
2 TRUE  20.8       1.20  17.6
```

However, I would like to have a third row which would perform the same computations without grouping. It would compute the average, median and standard deviation for the whole sample, without conditioning on the group. What's the easiest way to do that within `tidyverse`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to just row bind a duplicate of the whole data where you `mutate()` the `FOMC` variable to `"ALL"` so that you end up with that as a separate group when you `group_by()` and `summarise()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

daily.SPY <- tibble(
  FOMC = factor(rep(c(T, F), each = 25)),
  Daily.Return = c(cumsum(rnorm(25)), cumsum(rnorm(25)))
)

daily.SPY %>% 
  bind_rows(., mutate(., FOMC = "ALL")) %>%
  group_by(FOMC) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = 100 * mean(Daily.Return),
            Median = 100 * median(Daily.Return),
            Vol = 100 * sqrt(252) * sd(Daily.Return/100))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   FOMC   Mean Median   Vol
#>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 ALL    58.4  -6.57  32.3
#> 2 FALSE -80.3 -53.6   13.9
#> 3 TRUE  197.  151.    30.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: :) thanks - honestly it's nearly identical so mostly comes down to aesthetic preference. Yours is great too - it's one of the fun things about this that there are often many right answers!

Comment: Thank you both! Both solutions are quite cool! I will accept this one since @kybazzi also thinks this is the best so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function for summarizing data:

```
summarize_returns = function(data) {
  data %>%
    summarise(
      Mean = 100 * mean(Daily.Return),
      Median = 100 * median(Daily.Return),
      Vol = 100 * sqrt(252) * sd(Daily.Return / 100),
      .groups = "drop"
    )
}
```

Then you can combine the two summaries using `dplyr::bind_rows()`:

```
data %>%
  group_by(FOMC) %>%
  summarize_returns() %>%
  bind_rows(
    data %>% summarize_returns() %>% mutate(FOMC = "Total")
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  FOMC     Mean Median   Vol
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 FALSE -13.6   -13.3   15.5
2 TRUE   14.4     8.79  16.6
3 Total   0.992  -1.08  16.2
```

My data:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
data = tibble(
  FOMC = as.character(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Daily.Return = rnorm(100)
)
```